# JavaScript code to detect user os

Tags: javascript, android, if-statement

I have this code to detect visitors operating system.

```
<script>var OSName="Unknown OS";
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

  document.write('Your OS: '+OSName);
</script>
```

But it detecta as Linux in Android phone I want to detect Android, windows, Linux,j2me,Mac and iOS Operating Systems

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Are you saying that when using Android it detects the OS as Linux?

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to show localhost:8080/Mobile/index.html for mobile visitors ,and show localhost:8080/desktop/index.html for desktop users

Comment: Hey guys, I've found it